# How to disable autofocus and set focus to infinity?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, focus

I almost never take any close up pictures with my Galaxy Nexus (and when I do, it'd be more convenient to manually switch into some kind of macro mode).

How do I stop the auto-focus from trying all possible focus positions every time I take a picture?

Such behaviour makes me lose all the good moments that I want to capture in the first place (due to a focus delay of about 3 to 5 seconds), and often results with pictures being taken out-of-focus, especially at night or through a windscreen or something.  Is there a way to disable such bogus autofocus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that ***Open Camera*** ([net.sourceforge.opencamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)) does contain a feature where the focus could be manually set to ***auto***, ***infinity***, ***macro***, ***manual*** (locked-on-touch) and ***continuous***.

[image: Open Camera, focus options]

It does appear to mostly work on a non-rooted Nexus 5 — changing the setting to ***infinity*** does remove the extra focusing delay prior to taking each picture (although it also appears to be buggy in such a way that changing from ***auto*** to ***infinity*** may sometimes leave the focus at the ***macro*** level, without refocusing at infinity).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's some way technically to simply shut off the autofocus, making the camera start up in a default focus and never moving away from that. It is however not a function that I am aware of that it exists in custom ROMS, because that's the only place you'll find modifications like this, and unless there's a big demand for it, it's unlikely someone will code it. I've got a feeling that camera focus might be really tricky to mod from the actual OS.

I think the only way you'll solve this for sure is basically learning to code and inspecting the AOSP source, or paying a developer to do it for you. I'm almost certain it's not a native function of the Android OS.

Comment: Isn't there some way to simply change some setting somewhere somehow?  Similar to how the plist settings are done on iOS and OS X?  I don't understand how this could not be a priority: does noone use Camera for taking any non-posing pictures?

Comment: As I said, I'm not aware of it being a native function of the Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Having just experienced a similar issue, I've found that the apps "Camera FV-5" and "Cinema FV-5" both have nice extra options, including ones affecting focus.  Worked for me, even if I'm not sure quite which buttons I hit.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment on my Samsung Galaxy A50 phone, you can lock the focus by:

- opening the camera app
- then pressing on the screen with your finger, on the spot where you want to lock the focus, for 1-2 seconds, and it should lock the focus until you tap the camera screen again